# Reduce Amount of Code CSS3 Animated Bar Graph?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm making an animated bar graph using CSS3. My [code can be viewed here](http://jsfiddle.net/9b50gtrn/). I'd like to (if possible) reduce the crazy amount of animations I have set in the CSS. Currently each bar on the graph uses it's own seperate animation which takes it from 0px width to a variable width that is exclusive to each bar. For example:

```
        @-webkit-keyframes bar4 {
            from {width: 0px;}
            to {width: 150px;}
        }

        /* Standard syntax */
        @keyframes bar4 {
            from {width: 0px;}
            to {width: 150px;}
        }
```

Is there anyway I can set up just one animation for all the bars so that I don't have to have separate animations for each bar? Like in php how you can just pass in a variable to a function, or some other alternative?

Comment: You can wrap each bars in a div with fixed width and animate the bar from 0 to 100%

Comment: anpsmn, thanks! I will try that. Why didn't you put that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: You kids today.  How do you think progress bars were originally made? ;-)

Comment: @DigitalBrent I was bit busy to write an answer and make a fiddle to demo it so thought better to comment. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fixed width divs as containers and animate your graph inside the container.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/1beyxxx9/

```css
            .bar {
              width: 0px;
              height: 25px;
              margin-top: 10px;
              background: #0CFF0E;
            }
            #div_1 {
              -webkit-animation: bar 1s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: bar 1s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_2 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar .15s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar .15s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_3 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar .30s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar .30s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_4 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar .45s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar .45s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_5 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar .60s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar .60s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_6 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar .20s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar .75s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_7 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar .90s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar .90s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_8 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar 1.05s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar 1.05s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            #div_9 {
              -webkit-animation: 1s bar 1.30s linear;
              /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
              animation: 1s bar 1.30s linear;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
            /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            @-webkit-keyframes bar {
              from {
                width: 0%
              }
              to {
                width: 100%;
              }
            }
```

```html
<div style="width:200px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_1'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:100px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_2'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:150px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_3'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:20px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_4'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:75px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_5'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:110px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_6'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:120px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_7'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:40px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_8'></div>
</div>
<div style="width:140px;">
  <div class="bar" id='div_9'></div>
</div>
```